# How to modify a selected text widget in tKinter when pressing a button?

Tags: python, tkinter, button, text

I have a program that uses text and button widgets. I want it to insert a string in the text widget when I press the button, but I have no idea of how to do that. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Please provide your code and produce a [Minimal Reproduction](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graphical user interfaces have the concept of *keyboard focus* (or *focus* for short). A widget with the focus will be the widget that gets keyboard events. Normally there can only be a single widget with the keyboard focus at any one time. For the most part, focus is handled automatically. For example, if you click in a text widget or entry widget, that widget will be given the focus.

The answer to your question is to call tkinter's `focus_get` method to get the widget with the keyboard focus. You can then call the `insert` method to insert text into that widget.

The following is a simple example. Click on any text widget and then click the button, and the string "Hello!" will be inserted in whichever text widget has the focus.

```
import tkinter as tk

def insert_hello():
    widget = root.focus_get()
    widget.insert("end", "Hello!")

root = tk.Tk()
button = tk.Button(root, text="Hello", command=insert_hello)
button.pack(side="top")
for i in range(3):
    text = tk.Text(root, width=40, height=4)
    text.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```